# Importing sql dump from postgresql 9.6 to postgresql 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4, phppgadmin, postgresql-10

I have a website with a Postgis database. I access to it with phpPgAdmin with postgreSQL 9.6. I want to export my database to keep a local backup.

I exported it like that:

[image: Export from PhpPgAdmin]

Then I want to import it in PgAdmin 4 v2.1, with PostgreSQL 10. In my SQL file I changed the owner name from `observatoire-vienne`  to `postgres`. I created an empty spatial database.
[image: empty spatial database]

I selected the query tool and ran the query with my sql file.

The error message is:

> ERROR: ERREUR: la fonction public._st_dumppoints(public.geometry, integer[]) n'existe pas

Which means:

> Error: the function public._st_dumppoints(public.geometry, integer[]) does not exist

I can’t find a similar problem in previous posts.

My question is: Is it due to Postgres versions? Does someone have the solution?

Comment: PostGIS is not installed in the new database

Comment: It is, I added a picture

Comment: So what's below the `Extensions` node?

Comment: plpgsql and postgis

Comment: You are probably restoring a dump from an old PostGIS version into a database with a newer PostGIS version. Current PostGIS does not have a `_st_dumppoints` function. What is the context of the error message? Maybe you should use `postgis_restore.pl` to load the dump.

Comment: I sent a message to my webhost asking for the postgis version. My postgis version in PgAdmin is 2.4.4.  To use postgis_restore.pl, I need to use the pgsql shell ?

Comment: the version is 2.3. I check on postgis.net, in 2.4 it is written : _ST_DumpPoints removed, was no longer needed after PostGIS 2.1.0 when ST_DumpPoints got reimplemented in C. Then how can I get around this problem ?